# get_category_parents to array wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok So I'm using wordpress and PHP.

Basicly I get a chosen category from a dropdown menu. I then find it's parents.

But then comes the part where I seem to fail. The output of $parents is a string with the names instead of the ID's.

So I try to get each word from the string into an array.
And loop through them and convert them to their ID number.

I commented out where it doesnt seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
//Create array
$categoriesArray = [];

//Get choice from wp-dropdown
$selected_val = $_POST['cat'];

//Get parents from choice divided by (this seems to output a string)
$parents = get_category_parents( $selected_val, true, ',' );

/*
//Make array from string
$categoriesArray = explode(",",$parents);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($categoriesArray); $i++) {
{
    $categoriesArray[$i] = get_cat_ID($categoriesArray[$i]);
}
*/

//the array should look something like this.
//$categoriesArray = ["21","44"];
```

Comment: //firstly, load data for your child category
    $child = get_category(31);
    
    //from your child category, grab parent ID
    $parent = $child->parent;
    
    //load object for parent category
    $parent_name = get_category($parent);
    
    //grab a category name
    $parent_name = $parent_name->name; // or id

Comment: That doesn't really help. My child can sometimes have 3 parents.
I need every parent to be within an array.

I'm using this array to create a new post and include this new post in all of these ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with the name of the category. I needed to use the slug instead of the name.

Here is my code that works. I can now make a new post and give it a category with their parents included!

```
//Create array
$categoriesArray = [];

//Get choice from wp-dropdown
$selected_val = $_POST['cat'];

//Get parents from choice divided by ,
$parents = get_category_parents( $selected_val, true, ',',false);

//Make array from string
$categoriesArray = explode(",",$parents);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($categoriesArray); $i++)
{
    $categoriesArray[$i] = get_cat_ID($categoriesArray[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this,

function get_level($cat, $level = 0)
{
if ($cat->category_parent == 0) {
    return $level;
} else {
    $level++;
    $cat = get_category($cat->category_parent);
    return get_level($cat, $level);
}

}

if (is_category()) {
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$your_cat = get_category($cat);

echo get_level($your_cat);
}
```